# Did lm-sensors affected my hardware in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, system-installation, graphics, lm-sensors

Yesterday I used `lm-sensors` in Ubuntu 23.04 to check my component's temperature. Everything worked fine, but then I used `sensor-detect` and said 'Yes' to every option (even the last one that updates `/etc/modules`).

After reboot, Ubuntu doesn't recognize correctly my NVIDIA MX130 GPU correctly anymore. When I tried to use `nvtop`, it showed only my integrated Intel Video Card (before using lm-sensors it recognized both), and I had problems with NVIDIA drivers because if I tried to reinstall them, just had errors and in the NVIDIA app that comes with drivers I had less options than before (just like if it know I had the NVIDIA Video Card but couldn't recognize it correctly).

I use Dualboot with Ubuntu and Windows 10. When I started Windows 10 after this incident, when I started World of Warcraft, it gave me an error telling that "hardware changed" and asking if I wanted to reset the game's settings to default. Ignoring that error, everything seems fine in Windows, and NVIDIA GPU is recognized with no problems.

I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, but since what happened, it just doesn't install well. I deleted the partition with Ubuntu, but when I want to install it again, it gets until the last part when is "setting up the system" then the window starts lagging and the progress bar doesn't move for a while, then it seems to respond and then again stops. When the installation window gets closed, Ubuntu doesn't show the typical message telling that installation ends. I restart the system, starts Ubuntu, and then it seems like didn't applied the config because there are a lot of packages not installed, NVIDIA drivers won't work well and I get errors when trying to reinstall them or even trying to update Ubuntu with the Software Update utility.

Tried twice to install Ubuntu again and get the same results, it doesn't recognize well my NVIDIA graphic card and the system gets installed without applying the settings I select in the installation process (like using Dark Mode).

I don't know what to do in this point. Maybe lm-sensors did something to the BIOS? Maybe I have to completely clean my SSD data an reinstall everything again (including Windows)?

Sorry if there's too much text, I wanted to give all possible details.

Comment: Today every device (graphics card, disk, ...) is a small computer (has cpu, ram, storage). Could be the kernel module which was activated by sensors-detect wrote something in the "graphics card" which lead to the situation. Maybe somebody knows how to "factory reset" the "graphics card". Maybe a tool from the vendor of the graphics card? Reinstalling the computer or resetting the computer bios usually does not reset the graphics card.